# In-App Purchase price range in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

We have stopped in-app purchase in our Android app but Play Store still shows the price range. Why? Is there a way to disable it in Google Play?

Comment: update the build without inappbilling permission on play store

Comment: The current build on Production does not have billing permission. Still it shows price range.

Comment: We have one build in beta channel as draft with inapp billing. Will that cause this?